# How can I determine the JSON offset position using Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse

I'm executing a javascript test, and I'm getting a syntax error stating: `...Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1618`  I'd like to use eclipse to find out where my syntax error is, but in Eclipse, I can only see the character locations by row:column.  Is there a way I can see the absolute character offset value of a json in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically meant to solve this problem, but you can do this with WTP's JSON Editor.

Create a text file with this tracing option on a line to itself (or append it to one you might already have):

```
org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/actioncontributor/debugstatusfields=true
```

Then, launch Eclipse but add the command line arguments `-debug thatfile` pointing to the file you created. The offset will show in the status bar below surrounded by square brackets.